# Win10 issue: all windows moved to left monitor in dual-screen RDP session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, display-settings, windows-10-v1803

Machine in question is on Windows 10 Enterprise, build 1803. When I remote in (RDP) from another machine with dual-monitors, ***all* of my open windows are forced over to the screen on the left**. I also use *virtual desktops* so it's pretty annoying to have to go through all of them, moving my windows back to the right monitor.

Is this a known bug of build 1803? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Same issue, posted in July '17: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2022730-windows-remote-desktop-windows-move-to-one-screen

Comment: Try this : Edit the RDP file in notepad, add the line `use multimon:i:1` to the file and save it. If there's already a line for "use multimon", change the value to 1.

Comment: You mean on the client machine, correct? The machine that is connecting _to_ my dual-screen host that has the issue?

Comment: yes, I mean the`.rdp` file.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do on the host machine itself though? That would be a much better solution. I sometimes remote in from a Mac too is the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the Mac too has this problem? That all windows move to the main display? This is weird. What RDP client are you using?

Comment: Yes, all machines I use to connect to my work machine have the problem.

Comment: Normally this is a problem with the client agent, not with the host. Does the change I suggested help on Windows?

Comment: The only home machine I have with dual monitors is a Mac, so I don't have a way to test. However, I am all but certain the issue is on the host, not the client machines...how would multiple machines with different OS's have the same issue? It has to be my Win10 host machine at work.